# Eloquent grouping of arrays - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have my models and relationships setup correctly in `laravel` and I can retrieve data using the code below;

```
$restaurants = Restaurant::with('restaurantClass', 'city', 'location', 'menuCategories', 'menuItems', 'menuModifierGroups', 'menuModifierItems')->where(['id' => $id])->get();
```

`restaurant` belongs to `'restaurantClass', 'city', 'location'`

`restaurant` has many `'menuCategories', 'menuItems', 'menuModifierGroups', 'menuModifierItems'`

I get my `data` like below;

```
[
  {
    // restaurant details here,
    "restaurant_class": {},
    "city": {},
    "location": {},
    "menu_categories": [],
    "menu_items": [],
    "menu_modifier_groups": [],
    "menu_modifier_items": []
  }
]
```

`menu_categories` has many `'menuItems', 'menuModifierGroups', 'menuModifierItems'`

How can I group them by `menu_categories`?
So basically group the inner arrays.

Comment: By _them_ you mean group `'menuItems', 'menuModifierGroups', 'menuModifierItems'` by `menu_categories` or do you mean group `restaurants`?

Comment: group the inner arrays by `menu_categories `

Comment: Yes but group what? the restaurants or do you want all of menuItems, menuModifierGroups and menuModifierItems grouped under menu_categories?

Comment: Yes under `menu_categories `

Comment: Did you have a look at `whereHas()` e.g. `Restaurant::with('restaurantClass', ....)->whereHas(["menu_categories" => function($query) { /* try to do grouping here */  })->get();` ? — don't know if it is possible